show thumbnails when selecting images in the file upload window
my page contains this code to select an image from a pc:
<input type="file" id="bc_imgItem" accept="image/*" onchange="imageUpload()">
when I do this, a window opens in which I see the images in a list. I need to see the thumbnails (previews) of the images. So that I can see what I want to upload. I hope there is a property in html that will do this.
I'm working on windows 11.
I have set up the explorer the right way. I see thumbnails of images when I open the directory, but it doesn't work when I open the window for uploading these images to the site.

The file explorer shown will vary based on your browser/operating system, I don't believe there's any way to request specific layouts via the input element. (Though, in Windows I believe you can choose to display images in the explorer for your local machine)

You can utilize URL.createObjectURL(YourImage) from your image file and use that as the SRC for your HTML image tag.

As stated, if you're talking about the OS (Operating System) "Select File" window that is opened when you "Browse" for a file, then you have no control over that

I found such a solution for myself:
1. Right click in an empty area of the image selection window
2. The view
3. Large icons.
but I will be waiting for an answer. Maybe there is a better solution.
